# The margin on my buttons won't work, they just stack up together all in one on the top right

Tags: html, css

I was trying to put my buttons from top to bottom on my html page in the upper right hand corner. They just all stack up there, the only way that I am able to unstack them is is I do the br tag 3 times between each button. Shouldn't the top and bottom margin deal with this?
If you run the code snippet you can see that all of the buttons stack together in the top right, I want them to be one on top of the other.

HTML and CSS code:

```css
.button {
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 7px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 8px;
  right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <a href="dinosaur.html"><button class="button">Dinosaur Game</button></a></button>
  <a href="slope.html"><button class="button">Slope</button></a>
  <a href="tunnel-rush.html"><button class="button">Tunnel Rush</button></a>
  <a href="2048.html"><button class="button">2048</button></a>
  <a href="ratatouille.html"><button class="button">Ratatouille</button></a>
</center>
```

Comment: Nesting interactive elements renders your HTML invalid. That is, **you cannot put a button in an anchor**. Also, the `center` tag has been deprecated around 22 years ago.

Comment: _"Shouldn't the top and bottom margin deal with this?"_ - no, not when you absolutely position them all in the exact same place. You completely take an element out of the normal layout flow with this, so it does not influence the position of following elements any more.

Answer (score -1):

For the buttons all stacked up, it is because you have  `position: absolute;` in the button styles.

For the buttons to align right, you can try wrapping the buttons in a flexbox like so:

```css
.button {
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 7px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 8px;
  right: 10px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="dinosaur.html"><button class="button">Dinosaur Game</button></a></button>
  <a href="slope.html"><button class="button">Slope</button></a>
  <a href="tunnel-rush.html"><button class="button">Tunnel Rush</button></a>
  <a href="2048.html"><button class="button">2048</button></a>
  <a href="ratatouille.html"><button class="button">Ratatouille</button></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about `center` tag and also `</button>` at the end of first link. **FLEX** must deal with the issue

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.button {
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 7px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 8px;
  right: 10px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
```

```html
    <main>
      <a href="dinosaur.html"><button class="button">Dinosaur Game</button></a>
      <a href="slope.html"><button class="button">Slope</button></a>
      <a href="tunnel-rush.html"><button class="button">Tunnel Rush</button></a>
      <a href="2048.html"><button class="button">2048</button></a>
      <a href="ratatouille.html"><button class="button">Ratatouille</button></a>
    </main>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `position:relative` and `display:block` attributes for `.button` class. I wrote it like below now works fine. I hope it works for you. Additionally if you want to align items to the right you can use which i wrote below `.right` class attributes in css codes.

```css
.button {
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 7px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 8px;
  position: relative;
  display:block;

}

.right {
display:flex;
align-items:flex-end;
flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="right">
  <a href="dinosaur.html"><button class="button">Dinosaur Game</button></a></button>
  <a href="slope.html"><button class="button">Slope</button></a>
  <a href="tunnel-rush.html"><button class="button">Tunnel Rush</button></a>
  <a href="2048.html"><button class="button">2048</button></a>
  <a href="ratatouille.html"><button class="button">Ratatouille</button></a>
</p>
```